# Download only a part of a torrent movie

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I am working on a media project that contains little clips from movies and I wonder if there any way to avoid downloading all of the data instead only the specified parts of the movies?

Comment: No, bittorrent isn't designed to do that. it just distributes files, it cares not how they are organized internally, so theres no clear predictable relationship between a block of data and the portion of content that it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a torrent of a movie is created, the movie is broken down into small pieces.  The number of these pieces is decided by the torrent application, either by the application default, or the user changing the settings.  There is no way to know in advance what chunks contain the data you need.  Also, even if you knew the data you wanted was in the last 1/3, just getting that last piece, you might be missing data required at the beginning of the file telling the player the format.

Comment: Well, actually, it's possible and simple to map Bittorrent pieces to specific parts of the file, it's just I don't know of any bittorrent program that actually does this.  I think the bigger issue is how to map a part of a file reliably to a specific range of time in a video - it would require the Bittorrent program to know about a myriad of video codecs and such, or trust the file/torrent itself to be tagged with that information.  This is more complicated if the video is in some sort of archive format.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. What [@Keltari](https://superuser.com/a/749972/214658) said is correct but using the idea from [@Joe Jack](https://superuser.com/a/1323614/214658) :
First use magnetic link and download into cloud using [seedr.cc](https://www.seedr.cc/files), then right click on the video file, copy download link and paste it at [Online video cutter](https://online-video-cutter.com/). Trim and download.

Of course the size or length of video is limited by seedr and Online-video-cutter limits.

Comment: I shall check those out.

Comment: I guess this works, but the online vide cutter you mentioned has a file size limit on the free tier

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for the same solution and so far the best I've found are torrent stream applications - one of the best is Ace Stream which literally opens a torrent for a video and streams a specific part on the timeline of your choosing. From here, you can record this chunk while playing.  Ace Stream is a modded version of VLC's media player so the recording function is still present.